# How do I raise a slack api exception

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am currently writing some unit tests for my slack bot that I am creating, and I would love to be able to throw slack API errors such as channel_not_found exceptions or not_in_channel exceptions to test if I handle them well. I have been able to find documentation of what each response looks like, but I don't know how to throw the exception itself. Is there a good way I can do this?

Comment: An HTTP request can't throw an exception, it's down to whichever library you're using to handle the cases with bad requests, so look at the documentation of your library